# What is the active form of "to be invited to"

Tags: passive-voice, active-voice, active-vs-passive

I have the following sentence:

> I will be more than happy to have an opportunity to be invited to your institution...

Microsoft Word complains on it: passive voice (consider revising).

**So my question is:** What is the active version of this sentence which will keep the formalism and positive attitude?

Comment: You can safely ignore Microsoft Word's advice about passive voice. However, I will be more than happy if you invite me...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because ELL isn't here to analyse the shortcomings of Microsoft Word's "grammar checker".

Comment: As @MichaelHarvey said, you can generally safely ignore Word's complaints about passive voice. However, I would re-cast the sentence entirely; ***I would welcome an invitation to your institution.***

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: Your rephrasing assumes the ***addressee*** is the one who issued (will issue) the invitation, but that's not necessarily the case. One important aspect of the passive form is that it ***might not specific the "agent"*** (perhaps the writer has been invited to the institution by someone completely different, feasibly not identified *anywhere* in the "conversation".

Comment: @FumbleFingers  -  That close isn't appropriate; the question is not about Word or the grammar checker.

Comment: Firstly, the "opportunity to be invited" is an overkill. You can either "be offered an opportunity to visit" or "be invited to visit". It's odd to be given an opportunity to be invited. Secondly, this is one of those cases where the active form would be significantly less "formal-sounding". It can be done (as others have stated) but it will not sound nearly as rife with decorum. Having said that, I would change the introductory words to match the level of formality: It would be an honour to be invited to your institution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will be more than happy to have an opportunity to be invited to your institution...

That's simple:

I will be more than happy to have your institution invite me to be a speaker. [or whatever]

Comment: As @unmonav points out in his comment above, the tone is less than ideal and the sentence is wordy.   You can either "be offered an opportunity to visit" or "be invited to visit".   (If "an opportunity to be invited"... it feels like:  'you get the opportunity to be invited!  are you actually invited?)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Word is correct, it is slightly stilted, and may sound a little bit grandiose, or too-formal, or just a little "off" - because of the passive voice, and also the "wordiness" (too many words).

A natural thing to say in informal or conversational speech is:

```
  I'd love to attend your institution...
```

or

```
  I'd love to visit your institution.
```

In ***very*** formal communication:

```
  At your convenience, I would like to visit your institution...
```

The first one is actually OK in most business or academic situations in the US at present, however.   (If you use the second, continue the sentence with the reason you want to visit or what you want to do there rather than ending it after 'institution'.)